# Python: How do i Remove a CERTAIN amount of decimal in a float

Tags: python, math, decimal

so i had this problem where i generated numbers from 0-1 with a step of 0.01 but the numbers have so many decimals like 0.010101010101.I only need it in the form 0.01 with two decimals.

How do i remove the rest of decimals ?

Comment: How exactly are you generating these numbers? What you observe can't be explained by the round-off error implicit in floats. You seem to be doing some sort of weird string concatenation. Either that or this in another duplicate of [is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4996248)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the decimal like

```py
your_value = 0.1010101010
desired_value = '%.2f' % your_value
```

Now `desired_value` will have the decimal upto 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use decimal.
Look at the documentation in the link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

Round num to digits places. `round(num, digits)`

Comment: This worked the best .Thank you